# How to serialize to JSON without using an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I want to serialize my variables to JSON so I can POST the JSON to an external API. I'd rather not make an separate model just to serialize these values.

It's not possible to use a Dictionary because the structure is **not** default like `"var" : "input"` , I'm struggling because one of the fields is structured like:  `"entryType" : { "name" : "Monitoring" }`.

Does anyone have an suggestion what's the best approach here?

```
var number = "MLD2101 0107";
var briefDescription = "Test";
var EntryType = "Monitoring";
```

Im trying to serialize the variables above into the following JSON:

```
  "number": "MLD2101 0107",
  "briefDescription": "Test",
  "entryType" : { "name" : "Monitoring" },
```

**Edit**

I Found the following solution from NewtonSoft:

```
JObject jsonObject =
    new JObject(
        new JProperty("number", number),
        new JProperty("briefDescription", briefDescription),
        new JProperty("entryType", 
            new JObject("name" , entryType))
    );
```

Comment: Why not use an anonymous object?

Comment: Excellent suggestion from @RomanMarusyk to use [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types).

Comment: And do you need to deserialize it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Newtonsoft JSON.NET then try this approach with an anonymous object

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
       number,
       briefDescription,
       entryType = new { name = EntryType }
    });
```

for System.Text.Json:

```
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
     {
        number,
        briefDescription,
        entryType = new { name = EntryType }
     });
```

Comment: Thank you! I've found an solution as can be seen in my edit, but using an anonymous object looks alot better

Comment: I have one issue with this solution, one of my JSON field names is "object" which is not allowed to use as an declarator. Do you know any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually nest Dictionaries, like so:

```cs
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new Dictionary<string, object> {
        {"number", "MLD2101 0107"},
        {"briefDescription", "Test"},
        {"entryType", new Dictionary<string, object> {
            { "name", "Monitoring" }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Wow I had no idea about this, that's pretty cool!